# Adding .indexOn for nested data

Tags: firebase

I am getting the firebase warning "Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "E-mail" at /user/544dceb6-98d-4f7e/clients.

The rule I added is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": {
      "$clients": {
        ".indexOn": ["E-mail"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the call I'm making:

```
firebaseRef.child(authData.uid + "/clients").orderByChild("E-mail").equalTo(this.props.params.clientId).on('value', function(clientSnapshot) { ... }
```

This is how my data is structured:

```
database
+ user
  + 544dceb6-98d-4f7e...
      + clients
          + -K96sXIXRUIOK8....
              + E-mail
```

I suspect the issue has something to do with the two layers of keys but can't find a solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing a level in your rules.json:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": {
      "$userid": {
        "clients": {
          ".indexOn": ["E-mail"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: it is somewhat confusing that you have `user` (singular) and `clients` (plural) in the tree. Making them consistent helps in keeping your data structure easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also thank you for your feedback on naming - I will clean that up.

Comment: What about own keys instead userid key?